# Rspec expect passing when it should not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

When I run the following test

```
RSpec.describe LessonsController, type: :controller do
 describe 'GET / index' do
    let(:lesson1) {FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)}
    let(:lesson2) {FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)}

    it 'returns an http success' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success

    end

    it 'returns all the lessons' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([])
      expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([lesson1, lesson2])

    end
  end
end
```

The second expect, `expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([lesson1, lesson2])`, fails with `expected: [#<Lesson id:...>, #<Lesson id:...>] got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`.

But then, when I run the following test and it all passes

```
RSpec.describe LessonsController, type: :controller do
 describe 'GET / index' do
    let(:lesson1) {FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)}
    let(:lesson2) {FactoryGirl.create(:lesson)}

    it 'returns an http success' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success

    end

    it 'returns all the lessons' do
      get :index
      expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([lesson1, lesson2])

    end
  end
end
```

I am wondering why is it that the second test does not fail? I was expecting the second spec to also fail with the same reason as the first one.

I believe it might be due to the let statement.

With that said, I am running rspec-rails, factory_girl_rails and Rails 4. I don't believe it is due to contamination because this effect still occurs even when I run the test in isolation (focus).

Comment: Are you cleaning out the database between specs? Otherwise its due to *test contamination*. https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: What exactly is the "2nd expect"? The `[]` one which is technically second in that file or the second in the second spec? Please add some line numbers and actual error output.

Comment: How do I add line numbers? I edited it for clarification.

Comment: can you please add code of your controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm guessing your controller has some code like this:

```
@lessons = Lesson.all
```

Remember, that returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which may not actually hit the database until the last moment it needs to. Also, once an `ActiveRecord::Relation` fetches its results, it *will not* re-fetch them unless you call `.reload`.

Secondly, remember how `let` works. Code for a `let` isn't evaluated until you try to access that a variable. So, you get a situation like this:

```
describe "Something" do 
  let(:lesson) { Lesson.create! }

  it "makes a lesson" do 
    # right now there are 0 lessons 
    lesson
    # calling `lesson` caused the lesson to be created, 
    # now there is 1 lesson
  end 
end
```

Third, when you turn an `ActiveRecord::Relation` into an Array, it executes the *real* database query (in this case, `select * from lessons`).

With those things in mind, we can contrast the two test cases.

In the first case, lessons are fetched from the database *before* the lessons are actually created:

```
it 'returns all the lessons' do
  get :index
  # No lessons have been created yet 
  # `select * from lessons` returns no results 
  expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([])

  # `lessons` is cached. It won't query the database again 
  # calling `lesson1` and `lesson2` creates two lessons, but it's too late 
  # the result has already been cached as []
  expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([lesson1, lesson2])
end
```

In the second case, the lessons are created *first*, then the database query is executed:

```
  get :index
  # calling `lesson1` and `lesson2` creates two lessons
  # then the AR::Relation runs a query and finds the two lessons
  expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([lesson1, lesson2])
```

To demonstrate this, here is an example that should pass:

```
get :index 
expect(assigns[:lessons]).to eq([])
# this causes the lessons to be created 
lessons = [lesson1, lesson2]
# use `.reload` to force a new query:
expect(assigns[:lessons].reload).to eq(lessons)
```

Also, you could use RSpec's `let!` to create the lessons *before* running the example.

Comment: That's awesome and an awesome explanation! With that said, can I assume that the expect statement is ran last? In `expect(a).to eq(b)`, `b` will be evaluated first and then `a`? (I think that would close any of the other gaps I have.)

Comment: I'm getting out of my depth but I _think_ `expect(a)` is evaluated first, then it starts on `.to(eq(b))`. For that part, it evaluates `eq(b)`, then passes the result into `.to(...)`. It's the `.to(...)` which triggers the SQL query (because it compares an Array to an AR::Relation).